# displaying a XML file in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

I want to display a regular XML or any other file in text format in JEditorPane..I don't want to display the content in html page... the content should be exactly the same as in file with line break..the XML file is located on local system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need syntax highlighting? 
or just show plain text?

If syntax try to use this
http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html

If not just use JTextArea or normal JEditorPane with default editor kit. And call setText() to set your content.