# syntax highlighting in JEditorPane

Tags: java, jeditorpane

i want to do tag hightlighting in jeditorpane. if i load a html file in jeditorpane then it should automatically highlight all tags with red foreground color...
for ex.

 &l tHTML &gt

Comment: possible duplicate of [dislaying a XML file in JEditorPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626125/dislaying-a-xml-file-in-jeditorpane)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a lot of success using the excellent [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) component. It's available under the LGPL license too.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's not supported. Code folding can be pretty complicated so if that's a requirement you'll probably have to reuse some other mature editors such as jEdit or consider using Netbeans as your application platform so can leverage its editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can either go

- The [JEdit](http://syntax.jedit.org/) way
- Check some [google code](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) project
- Or go see what [Kiril](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=355) thinks about it.